# Turn all git commits thus far into single commit and erase all that history

Tags: git

I find my self committing tiny changes all the time to my initial commits to GIT HUB .

All the commit history from this is useless .

Often I just keep committing and deleting the repo and remaking the repo etc .

Im vaguely aware that I can turn a bunch of commits into a single commit but when I push that to the remote will all that trash history still be there ?

Is there a way to turn a bunch of commits into the first commit and then shred that history .

Comment: What's wrong with having lots of small commits? That's what git is good at..

Comment: Instead of committing all the time you can just keep going until you feel you are done, and then [`git add --patch [FILE]`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) and commit related changes. This may help with lots of commits that all belong together. It also allows you to focus on the work, instead of continuously thinking about committing stuff. damian is also right; there is nothing inherently wrong with lots of commits.

Comment: nothings wrong with a bunch of small commits at all . these commits are just a bunch of typo fixes and style changes during my initial upload of a project and have nothing to do with the project it self just its appearance on git . These changes are just a distraction to the people who actually have to program XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To forget the history so far, you can start a new orphan branch:

```
git checkout --orphan new-start
git commit -a
```

After this, you can poiny master to this new branch using

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard new-start
```

Be warned that this operation may lose information that can't be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

> All the commit history from this is useless

Sounds to me like you're using a branch in order to implement a certain feature or do a bugfix, then merge this branch into master and don't want to see all those small commits in master rather than seeing *one polished* commit that tells you

```
Implemented feature a
```

To do this, you could either `git rebase master` your branch before merging and adjust the history to your needs **or** do a `git merge --squash` into master which will squash all your commits of your branch into one.

Once you've done this, push your new master with your one fresh commit to github and delete your feature branch.

Comment: kind of I'm actually just being lazy and pushing a bunch of commits during my initial upload to tweak the style of the README.md page ; )